# select box auto select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create auto select box using `jQuery` or `JavaScript`.I have four select box. If I choose one select box from every select box, I want to choose auto select for other select box. Now, my design is depending on first select box. How can I do that ? Please help me.

**html**

```
<select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option value="1">Fruit</option>
    <option value="2">Animal</option>
    <option value="3">Bird</option>
    <option value="4">Car</option>
</select>

<select name="select2" id="select2">
    <option value="1">Banana</option>
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="1">Orange</option>
    <option value="2">Wolf</option>
    <option value="2">Fox</option>
    <option value="2">Bear</option>
    <option value="3">Eagle</option>
    <option value="3">Hawk</option>
    <option value="4">BWM<option>
</select>

<select name="select3" id="select3">
    <option value="1">Fruit</option>
    <option value="2">Animal</option>
    <option value="3">Bird</option>
    <option value="4">Car</option>
</select>
```

**javascript**

```
var $select1 = $( '#select1' ),
    $select2 = $( '#select2' ),
    $select3 = $( '#select3' ),
    $select4 = $( '#select4' ),
$option2 = $select2.find( 'option' ),
$option3 = $select3.find( 'option' ),
$option4 = $select4.find( 'option' );
$select1.on( 'change', function() {
$select2.html( $option2.filter( '[value="' + this.value + '"]' ) ),
$select3.html( $option3.filter( '[value="' + this.value + '"]' ) ),
$select4.html( $option4.filter( '[value="' + this.value + '"]' ) );
} ).trigger( 'change' );
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? You get any errors? Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Can you give an example?  Something like if `select option 1 = fruit` and `select option 2 = orange` then `select option 3` will automatically select 'Fruit'.  Is that it?

Comment: Or maybe you asking for select fruit in first select box and all other select boxes will be limit to fruits options (or animals ...)

Answer (score 2):

for me I think it's a bad thing to duplicate the options value .. so you need to use `data` attribute it will help you to get the right value in the next selection .. you can use the next code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#select1').on('change' , function(){
    var getVal = $(this).val();  // get value from the 1st select
    $('#select2 option').hide(); // hide all option for the 2nd select
    $('#select2 option[data-value="'+getVal+'"]').show().first().prop('selected' , true);  // show the options which data-value = the first select value and select the 1st one of them
    $('#select3 option').hide();  // while you don't have duplicated value on select3 you can just use value instead of using `data` attribute 
    $('#select3 option[value="'+getVal+'"]').show().prop('selected' , true);
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select1" id="select1">
      <option value="1">Fruit</option>
      <option value="2">Animal</option>
      <option value="3">Bird</option>
      <option value="4">Car</option>
  </select>

  <select name="select2" id="select2">
      <option data-value="1" value="1">Banana</option>
      <option data-value="1" value="2">Apple</option>
      <option data-value="1" value="3">Orange</option>
      <option data-value="2" value="4">Wolf</option>
      <option data-value="2" value="5">Fox</option>
      <option data-value="2" value="6">Bear</option>
      <option data-value="2" value="7">Eagle</option>
      <option data-value="3" value="8">Hawk</option>
      <option data-value="4" value="9">BWM<option>
  </select>

<select name="select3" id="select3">
  <option value="1">Fruit</option>
  <option value="2">Animal</option>
  <option value="3">Bird</option>
  <option value="4">Car</option>
</select>
```

**Explanation:**  *What code above doing* When change select1

- get the value selected
- hide all options on 2nd select
- show options which data-value attribute equal the value selected from the 1st select
- select the first one of them

**while you don't have duplicated values on select3** but if you've duplicated values you can use `data` attribute which used with select2

- hide all options on 3rd select
- show option which `[value]` attribute equal the value selected from the 1st select and select it

Answer (score 1):

you need to store your values in arrays and according to your first dropdown selection you need to assign respected array values to seccont dropdown

I cant understand what is dropdown2 and dropdown3?

```
var $select1 = $( '#select1' ),
    $select2 = $( '#select2' ),
    $select3 = $( '#select3' ),
    $select4 = $( '#select4' ),
$option2 = $select2.find( 'option' ),
$option3 = $select3.find( 'option' ),
$option4 = $select4.find( 'option' );

var objectTypeValues = ['Fruit','Animal','Bird','Car'];
var fruiteValues = ['Banana','Apple','Orange',''];
var carValues = ['BWM'];
var animalValues = ['Wolf','Fox','Bear'];
var birdValues = ['Eagle','Hawk'];


$select1.on( 'change', function() {
  var valuesTobeBind = null;
  console.log(this.value);
  switch(this.value){
    case 'Fruit':
      valuesTobeBind = fruiteValues;
        break;
      case 'Animal':
      valuesTobeBind = animalValues;
        break;
      case 'Bird':
      valuesTobeBind = birdValues;
        break;
      case 'Car':
      valuesTobeBind = carValues;
        break;
  }

  $select2.html('');
  var selecthtml;
  for (var i = 0; i<=valuesTobeBind.length; i++){        
    selecthtml+='<option value="'+  valuesTobeBind[i]+'">'+  valuesTobeBind[i]+'</option>';
  }
  $select2.html(selecthtml);

});
```

Please ignore `select3` and `select4` from my code